# Incorrect assembler output for Lisp compiller

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, cpu-registers, gnu-assembler

I am writing a Lisp compiler for x86. I have been trying to debug it because for certain variable declarations it produces the wrong output code. Here was the code that I gave it:

```
(define y (+ 1 2))
(define x 6)
(display x)
```

I was expecting an output of 6. However, it outputs zero. I have narrowed it down to a certain part of the code, which is below.

I am assembling with GAS on MacOS:
`gcc -masm=intel overflow_q.asm`

```
    .global _main
    .text
_main:
    push 1  # arg 2 for proc +
    push 2  # arg 1 for proc +

    pop rsi  # begin plus
    pop rdi
    add rdi, rsi  # end plus
    push rdi  # for the caller of +

    pop rax  # get result in rax
    mov [y + rip], rax  # put computed value of 3 into y
    mov rsi, [x + rip]  # put value of x, 6, into rsi

    /*
    I have not included the code for the call to "display"
    because it's irrelevant - and the program still fails
    in the same way without it
    */

    /*
    The bug:
    RSI turns out to be zero here! Why is that happening?
    I know this given the exit code returned from running it.
    */

    mov rdi, rsi
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall

    .data
y:
    .long 0  # initialize with a value of zero
x:
    .long 6
```

Comment: `.long` is a 32 bit variable. You want `.quad` for 64 bit. Your store to `y` overwrites `x`. A debugger should have showed you that. Also looking at disassembly should have showed the overlap.

Comment: Why does the store to y overwrite x? That confuses me a bit - but using .quad for 64 bit variables, along with 64-bit registers makes sense to me.

Comment: Because you only allocated 32 bits to `y` and wrote 64 bits to it with `rax`. So the following 32 bits were overwritten but those belong to `x`. Either change to 32 bit registers or change your data type to 64 bit.

Comment: @Jester Aha! I'll try fixing it and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Jester Works like a charm.